# JAVA outputStream write nothing (outputStream.close was not help)

Tags: java, android, sockets, outputstream

I connect to a wifi and use socket to send data. This is a server, and it can correctly get data by inputStream. But outputStream cannot send data back. I add outputStream.close(); but still not work.

After the thread create a ServerSocket, it will call socket thread to do input output.

```
public class SocketThread {
    Socket socket ;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private String resultJSON ;
    public SocketThread( Socket socket ){ // construct
        this.socket = socket ;
        try {
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void run() { // any message from client
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;
        try {
            bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
            resultJSON = new String(buffer,0,bytes);
            System.out.println("GET : "+ resultJSON);
            write(buffer,bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void write(byte[] buffer, int bytes){ 
        try {
            outputStream.write(buffer);
            outputStream.close();
            System.out.println("WRITE : "+new String(buffer,0,bytes));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void cancel() { // after connect, we need to close the socket
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("cancel is wrong");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

//======================================================

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private SocketThread socketThread;
    private String resultJSON;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(); // create a server
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("10.10.100.35", 8000)); 
            while (true){
                System.out.println("wait"); 
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // wait call
                System.out.println("OK"); 
                connected(socket); // if called, connect it
                socketThread.cancel();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void connected(Socket socket) {
        if (socketThread != null) { // clear socketThread first
            socketThread.cancel();
            socketThread = null;
        }

        socketThread = new SocketThread(socket); // new a Thread
        socketThread.run(); // go
    }
};
```

Comment: `This is a server` ? Unclear. Who is a server? This Android code?

Comment: You should show your server code as we do not know how the server is going to read the bytes you just wrote.

Comment: Add a `"\n"` at the end.

Comment: I have updated my code. Thank you.

Comment: use `outputStream.flush();` instead of `outputStream.close();`

Comment: `socketThread.cancel();` That makes no sense. You just called run() on it. Remove.

Comment: i had tried to use outputStream.flush(); but still not work